# La fille du coupeur de joints / "le coup du Zeppelin" ?

Tags: sens, paroles-de-chanson

Dans une chanson d'[Hubert-Félix Thiéfaine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hubert-F%C3%A9lix_Thi%C3%A9faine) intitulée ["La fille du coupeur de joints"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JAv8UPSKF7g), je trouve le vers suivant :

> Elle nous fait le coup du Zeppelin

La chanson est gaillarde et le caractère grivois des derniers mots paraît évident mais j'aimerais savoir ce que signifie **exactement** cette expression. Merci de votre aide.

---

I read in a song written by [Hubert-Félix Thiéfaine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hubert-F%C3%A9lix_Thi%C3%A9faine) (["La fille du coupeur de joints"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JAv8UPSKF7g)) the following words :

> Elle nous fait le coup du Zeppelin

These are clearly bawdy lyrics but I'd like to know the **exact** meaning of the phrase "le coup du Zeppelin". Any help would be appreciated !

Comment: C'est une expression qu'il a inventé pour l'occasion, donc notre avis vaut ce qu'il vaut, on aura pas de réponse définitive. Je pense aussi immédiatement a Hindenburg, je pense que c'est une métaphore sexuelle.

Comment: Ou elle laisse échapper un gaz.

Comment: Je ne retrouve en effet cette expression que dans cette chanson... Vu le contexte il semble quasi sur qu'il s'agit de quelque chose de sexuel, mais quoi ? Cela me rend curieux :-) Cela dit je fais parfois aussi ce genre de blagues, par exemple quand un ami a mal au dos, "Alors, tu as trop fait la brouette tokinoise hier ?", ce qui ne se rapporte à rien si ce n'est à une position fictive du kamasutra...

Answer (score 3):

Quand on me dit Zeppelin hors contexte musical, je pense immédiatement à l'accident du [Hindenburg](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/LZ_129_Hindenburg) en 1937.

Sans doute que la fille du coupeur de joints s'enflamme facilement et montre une expressivité explosive dans certaines circonstances.

Ou bien quelque chose à voir avec la forme et les proportions du dirigeable.

Ou les deux.

Comment: Une circonstance comme lors de l'écrasement peut-être ? Chronologiquement ds. la chanson leur état d'esprit semble changer avant qu'elle leur fit fumer de sa paille, et ils avaient exprimé leur désir plus tôt ds. la chanson semble-t-il, mais elle s'est peut-être tout simplement allongée pour fumer un joint, donc l'ascension, le _high_ et ils étaient heureux entrevoyant leur altitude prochaine, moyennant compensation ? Un zeppelin monte et descend assurément, peut être un projectile, on peut p.-ê. aussi penser à un pétard, mais encore ? C'est curieux tout ça. Merci !

Answer (score 1):

le zeppelin est un modèle de pipe, la forme ne laisse pas de place au doute sur la signification.

Comme la "Pipe Vauen Zeppelin" Voir : http://www.pipephil.eu/oddpipes/pipcig/zeppelin1.html

A+

Comment: Une référence serait la bienvenue.

Answer (score 0):

Quelle est la forme et la consistance d’un zeppelin ? Avant et après gonflage ? J’Y verrais plutôt une intervention buccale. Pour le gonflage bien sûr...